# Measure the time of a child process

Tags: c++

I want to measure the time of a child process

```
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    ...
    time t begin, end, diff;
    ...
    //fork etc in here
    time(&begin);
    ...
    //some things
    ...
    time(&end);
    return 0;
}
```

I have 2 Time stamps now, is there a way to format it to the run-time of the child process to hours:minutes:seconds?

I have tried

```
diff = end - begin;
```

But I get a huge number then.

(Sorry for only a part of the code but it's on another PC.)

Comment: A "huge number" like what?  Can you print out "begin" and "end" and show us what they are?

Comment: start: Tue Dec 8 15:15:28 2015
end : Tue Dec 8 15:15:36 2015
runtime(diff) : 1449586236

Comment: How did you print those?  Usually time_t is a number.  What OS are you on?

Comment: How about making an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I used ctime(&end) for example to print start/end, im using linux

Comment: I think the bug is probably somewhere in the `...`s, which is why I *really* think you should create an MCVE.  But one thing to check specifically - since you are forking in there somewhere, are you sure that `begin` and `end` are both set in the process which prints them?  For instance, if you only set `begin` in the child, but compute the difference in the parent, it will be uninitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the difference with [`difftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/difftime):

```
double diff_in_seconds = difftime(end, begin);
```

or, for better precision, use one of C++11 [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) monotonic clocks such as [std::steady_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock):

```
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
// some things
auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
double time_in_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<double>(end - start).count();
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18685338/471164) for details why you should use a monotonic clock.

Comment: Hello, i just tried it. So first time was 16:27:47 and second 16:27:55. The result of difftime was 1.44959e+09. Thanks for the second way but i want to use time()

Comment: what is nearly the same thing like diff = end - begin if i cast it to an int

Comment: Interesting. Try printing the values of begin and end just after the time functions and just before the difftime. Perhaps they are overwritten/corrupted somewhere in between.

Comment: Ok, i just tried it and the begin was set to the Jan 1 1970 :D

Comment: i fixed it ty very much. i placed the time(&begin) at the wrong place !

Answer (score 1):

You should probably compute the difference using `difftime` instead of subtraction, in case your system uses some other format for `time_t` besides "integer number of seconds".

`difftime` returns the number of seconds between the two times, as a `double`.  It's then a simple matter of arithmetic to convert to hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: thanks, but i get the result 1.44959e+09, when icast it to an int its nearly the same thing like my first result.

Comment: @Raccoon20: Then you probably have a bug somewhere else.  Let me reiterate the suggestion I made in my comment to post an MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

The attempt in the question is a C way, not C++. In C++11 (assuming you have one), you can get 2 time points and then cast the difference between them to the units you need, as in the example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast

Nearly copying the code:

```
auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// Call your child process here
auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
std::cout << "Child process took "
          << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
          << " milliseconds\n";
```

Comment: This will return the whole number of milliseconds which is not a good idea if the time is small (of the order of milliseconds).

Comment: @vitaut, as mentioned in the text of the answer, there are 3 items in the code: 1-2) getting the time points 3) casting to some units. The OP didn't specify the most convenient units to measure the run time of his/her child process, so I could only guess. Large units for small running times are worse than small units for large running times.