# What is the default unit of time of c++'s chrono?

Tags: c++, profiling

I used this code to measure the runtime of my program from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11062846/3127121)

```
auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

/* do some work */

auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto elapsed = end - start;
std::cout << elapsed.count() << '\n';
```

I only needed to measure the runtime to look for a trend but I am kind of curious as to what unit that is.

Comment: You ccan easily convert to whatever units you want, then count those.  As far as I know, the units the system clock uses are not specified, other than by the type it returns.  But I am not reliable on this subject.

Comment: Btw, `system_clock` is the one you shouldn't use in this case.

Comment: [`system_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) -> [`duration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).

Answer (score 4):

You can easily check by your self, with this code:

```
using Clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
using Duration = Clock::duration;
std::cout << Duration::period::num << " , " << Duration::period::den << '\n';
```

On my system it prints:

```
 1 , 1000000000
```

That is, a period in terms of *nanoseconds* (i.e. 10<sup>−9</sup>s).

Answer (score 2):

**It's unspecified by the standard.**

> **20.12.7.1 Class system_clock** [time.clock.system]
>   Objects of class system_clock represent wall clock time from the system-wide realtime clock.
>   class system_clock {
>   public:
>   **typedef see below rep;**
>   **typedef ratio< unspecified , unspecified > period**;
>   **typedef chrono::duration< rep, period> duration**;
>   typedef chrono::time_point time_point;
>   static constexpr bool is_steady = unspecified ;
>   static time_point now() noexcept;
>   // Map to C API
>   static time_t to_time_t (const time_point& t) noexcept;
>   static time_point from_time_t(time_t t) noexcept;
>   };
>   **typedef unspecified system_clock::rep**;

Personally, I think it's always a good idea to explicitly convert the result to some specific `duration` you want.