# Timing a function in C++ using chrono and printing result

Tags: c++, cout, c++-chrono

I am trying to time a function in C++. To this extent I have tested the following code

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << t.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

I attempt to compile this in my console by

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ test3.cpp -o test5
```

as my C++-file name is test3.cpp. However, it gives me a long list of errors when it tries to compile the code:

```
test3.cpp:7:15: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1, 1000000000>>>::duration' (aka 'std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1, 1000000000>>'))
    std::cout << t.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
    ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:116:3: note: candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') to 'std::byte' for 1st argument
  operator<< (byte  __lhs, _Integer __shift) noexcept
```

It works completely fine when I replace the t.time_since_epoch() by a string. Also, if I define a variable in the script with t.time_since_epoch(), i.e.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto t2 = t.time_since_epoch();
    std::cout << "test" << '\n';
}
```

This gets compiled with no errors. So it seems that the t.time_since_epoch() works, but my cout-function does not know how to print it. Any ideas on how to fix this? According to this post:
[std::chrono and cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889136/stdchrono-and-cout)
the code should be working.

Comment: std::chrono is not a good way to measure performance. If you're going to do it use std::chrono:;steady_clock (high_resolution clock may actually be std::chrono::system_clock, a clock that can go backward in time!).  For performance measurements you can use  https://nanobench.ankerl.com/ a header file only library. Just make sure you first compile all the functions you want to test in a static library so you can link with both test and production executables later. And in general you can use profiling tools for your executable too

Comment: Use google benchmark. Here is online site with some demo: https://quick-bench.com/ anyway you are making beginners mistakes, so it is to soon for you to write any kind of benchmark. Master C++ basics first.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Thank you for the response, I will check out nanobench.ankerl.com later. I will make sure to use steady clock until then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is legal C++20.  Unfortunately libc++ has not yet implemented this part of C++20.

You can use my [free, open-source, header-only C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) as a workaround until your vendor fully implements C++20:

```
#include "date/date.h"  // add this
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using date::operator<<;  // add this
    auto t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << t.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

Example output:

```
1666477458303541ns
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works as of libc++ version 17: [godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/n8bG5Yefb). Previous versions didn't implement `operator<<` for `std::chrono::duration`.

In the meantime you could use either [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) or [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library. Here's an example using {fmt} ([godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/MbsbhE4Gr)):

```cpp
#include <fmt/chrono.h>

int main() {
  auto t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  fmt::print("{}", t.time_since_epoch());
}
```

Also note that you should use `steady_clock` and not `high_resolution_clock` (at least not without checking if it is monotonic) for timing a function for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18685338/471164).

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.