# Specialization of variadic constructor template of class template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Here's a class with variadic constructor and it's specializations for copy and move from a temporary.

```
template<class Obj>
class wrapper {
protected:
   Obj _Data;
public:

   wrapper(const wrapper<Obj>& w): _Data(w._Data) {}

   wrapper(wrapper<Obj>&& w):
      _Data(std::forward<Obj>(w._Data)) {}

   template<class ...Args>
   wrapper(Args&&... args):
      _Data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

   inline Obj& operator()() { return _Data; }

   virtual ~wrapper() {}
};
```

When I use one of specializations like this

```
wrapper<int> w1(9);
wrapper<int> w2(w1);
```

I'm getting the error: type of `w1` is deduced as `int`.

Output from VS2012:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'win::util::wrapper<int>' to 'int'
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting bitten by the greedy perfect forwarding constructor.

```
wrapper<int> w2(w1);
```

In the line above, the perfecting forwarding constructor is a better match as compared to the copy constructor, because `Args` is deduced as `wrapper<int>&`.

A quick fix solution is to change the line above to

```
wrapper<int> w2(static_cast<wrapper<int> const&>(w1));
```

this correctly calls the copy constructor but, besides being unnecessarily verbose, doesn't solve the basic problem.

To solve the original problem, you need to conditionally disable the perfect forwarding constructor when `Args` is the same as `wrapper<Obj>`.

[Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205121901/http://flamingdangerzone.com:80/cxx11/2012/06/05/is_related.html) an excellent blog post describing the problem, and how to solve it. To summarize, you need to change the perfect forwarding constructor definition to

```
template <typename... Args,
          DisableIf<is_related<wrapper<Obj>, Args...>::value>...>
wrapper(Args&&... args):
    _Data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

where `is_related` is defined as

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
struct is_related : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_related<T, U> : std::is_same<Bare<T>, Bare<U>> {};
```

and `Bare` is

```
template <typename T>
using Bare = RemoveCv<RemoveReference<T>>;
```

`RemoveCv` and `RemoveReference` are alias templates for `std::remove_cv` and `std::remove_reference` respectively.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9b7a1e17e580291)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `is_related<wrapper<Obj>, Args>>...`? Also, why should it disable if the types are the same?

Comment: @0x499602D2 No, `Args` needs to be expanded within `is_related` because you want the primary `is_related` template to be selected when `sizeof...(Args)!=1`. You want to disable it when the types are the same because in that case you want the copy/move constructor to be selected instead of the perfect forwarding one.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that the primary template had template pack. Anyway, you're saying that if one does `wrapper<int> w(x, y, z)` where `{x, y ,z}` are all type `Obj` (meaning `int`) then the constructor template *shouldn't* be chosen? I assume that you think they shouldn't because you're using `DisableIf`. But I think it should be `EnableIf`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Turns out there was an error in the code, I needed to pass the static data member `value` from `is_related` to `DisableIf`, not the whole type itself. And I'm saying if one does `wrapper<int> w(x)`, or `wrapper<int> w(std::move(x))`, where `x` is `wrapper<int>`, then the constructor template should not be selected. I've added a coliru link too.

Comment: Should a parameter pack be the last template parameter?

Comment: I guess I had solve this problem: I wrote Praetorian's code and my analagous in VS2012 with [Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515) and nothing was compiled. This is because one does not support SFINAE. Thanks everybody!

Comment: @wowofbob That compiler certainly supports the SFINAE being used here, but its support for variadic templates is very buggy. It also doesn't support alias templates, so the above solution will be horribly verbose. Your best option is to upgrade to VS2013.

Comment: @Praetorian I guess I'll do so)

Comment: @Praetorian I tryed your solution on VS2013 and it was not compiled.  The reason is because yours `DisableIf` in constructor template follows a template parameter pack `Args`. Maybe this trick is not allowed in VS. The full error message with working solution can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/79fAkvVh). I used your staff and added to constructor additional default template parameter which could be undefined when `Args` is a single parameter related with `wrapper<Obj>`

Comment: The blog link is broken :c I found *some* version [here](https://github.com/rmartinho/flamingdangerzone/blob/master/_posts/cxx11/2012-06-05-is_related.md), though it's not very readable.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is instantiating the constructor template on this line:

```
wrapper<int> w2(w1);
```

because the type of `w1` is `wrapper<int>&` and overload resolution rules dicate that an exact match is preferable to a conversion. The constructor which takes a `const wrapper<Obj>&` requires a `const` qualification, while `wrapper<Obj>&&` is an rvalue-reference which can't bind to lvalues.

Normally, non-template overloads are a preferred target than template ones (thus in a normal situation the copy-constructor would be chosen), but because the constructor template takes a [*universal reference*](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), it can deduce the type as an `int` making a perfect match and is therefore chosen, hence the error when the argument is forwarded.

As a fix, you can disable the perfect forwarding constructor through SFINAE in certain contexts as described in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205121901/http://flamingdangerzone.com:80/cxx11/2012/06/05/is_related.html) and by [@Praetorian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391184/specialization-of-variadic-constructor-template-of-class-template/21392046#21392046).

Comment: That's a bit of a drastic solution, isn't it? Perfect forwarding constructors are very handy when creating wrappers such as these. You can disable them using SFINAE to prevent this problem. R.MartinhoFernandes describes how do to do this in [this](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/06/05/is_related.html) post.

Comment: @Praetorian Interesting! Okay, I will change it. :)

Comment: Nit-pick: Binding an expression to `const wrapper<Obj>&` directly (i.e. w/o creating a temporary) is still ranked an Exact Match. There's a special rule in [over.ics.rank]/3 that disambiguates the situation. Similarly, non-template functions are only preferred over function templates if all argument conversions have the same "rank" (none is worse, the rank is part of that) [over.match.best]/1.

Answer (score 0):

For me, using a more granular version of Praetorian's example worked for me. <s>I defined something like `is_compat<T, Arg>`, and then feed this into an `std::enable_if<>` expression (leveraging `std::decay<>` to simplify matching).</s>

**EDIT**: Found `std::is_convertible`, MUCH simpler.

Self-Contained Example:

- [tpl_spec_greedy.cc](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/tree/52a1efe/cpp_quick/tpl_spec_greedy.cc) - Source file (also uses [name_trait.h](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/tree/52a1efe/cpp_quick/name_trait.h)
- [tpl_spec_greedy.output.txt](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/tree/52a1efe/cpp_quick/tpl_spec_greedy.output.txt)

Inline Example:

```
#include <type_traits>
// Syntactic sugar
using std::enable_if;
using std::is_convertible;
template<bool Expr, typename Result = void>
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<Expr, Result>::type;
template<typename From, typename To>
using enable_if_convertible_t = enable_if_t<is_convertible<From, To>::value>;
```

Then you can do overloads like:

```
template<typename ... Args>
void my_func(Args&& ... args) {
    cout << "1. my_func<Args...>(" << name_trait_list<Args&&...>::join() << ")" << endl;
}

// Use template with enable_if to catch as many types as possible
template<typename T1,
    typename = enable_if_convertible_t<T1, string>>
void my_func(int y, T1&& z) {
    cout
        << "2. my_func<T1:string>(int, " << name_trait<decltype(z)>::name()
        << ")" << endl;
}

// Example using multiple types (let compiler handle the combinatorics)
template<typename T1, typename T2,
    typename = enable_if_t<is_convertible<T1, string>::value &&
                           is_convertible<T2, double>::value>>
void my_func(int y, T1&& z, T2&& zz) {
    cout
        << "3. my_func<T1:string, T2:double>(int, "
        << name_trait<decltype(z)>::name() << ", "
        << name_trait<decltype(zz)>::name() << ")" << endl;
}
```

(NOTE: `name_trait*` is a home-baked class)

Example output:

```
>>> ( my_func(1, 2, 5, string("!!!")) );
1. my_func<Args...>(int&&, int&&, int&&, std::string&&)

>>> ( my_func(3, string("Hello")) );
2. my_func<T1:string>(int, std::string&&)

>>> ( my_func(4, (const string&)string("kinda")) );
2. my_func<T1:string>(int, const std::string&)

>>> ( my_func(5, "World") );
2. my_func<T1:string>(int, const char[6]&)

>>> ( my_func(6, var) );
2. my_func<T1:string>(int, char[6]&)

>>> ( my_func(7, var, 12) );
3. my_func<T1:string, T2:double>(int, char[6]&, int&&)

>>> ( my_func(9, var, 12.0) );
3. my_func<T1:string, T2:double>(int, char[6]&, double&&)
```

Comment: As an alternative, rather than having several template types, you could try combining logic using `&&`, something like `enable_if_t<is_compat_v<string, T1> && is_compat_v<double, T2>`.

Comment: Nope, can't, at least C++1y. My attempt: [diff for tpl_spec_greedy.cc](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/commit/b425bac).

Comment: Second update: Yes, you can; I was just doing something wrong with templated `using` statements.