# What pattern matching (if any) is applied for C++ variadic template function invocation?

Tags: c++, templates

I just naïvely wrote this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template< class... Args >
auto format_for( Args... args, int last_arg )
    -> char const*
{
    // using Specifier = char const [3];
    // static Specifier const s[] = { {'%', 'f'+(0*args), ' '}..., {'%', 'f', 0} };
    return reinterpret_cast<char const*>( "" );
}

auto main() -> int
{
    printf( "'%s'\n", format_for( 5, 2, 1 ) );
}
```

It crashes Visual C++ 2015 update 1, an **ICE** (Internal Compiler Error), and g++ 5.1.0 maintains that the function only takes one argument, presumably as a result of ignoring the `Args` after failing to match this template parameter:

```
C:\my\forums\so\081> cl printf.cpp /Feb
printf.cpp
printf.cpp(14): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\cxx\dymto.c', line 6771)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
 Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information

C:\my\forums\so\081> g++ printf.cpp
printf.cpp: In function 'int main()':
printf.cpp:14:43: error: no matching function for call to 'format_for(int, int, int)'
     printf( "'%s'\n", format_for( 5, 2, 1 ) );
                                           ^
printf.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: template<class ... Args> const char* format_for(Args ..., int)
 auto format_for( Args... args, int last_arg )
      ^
printf.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
printf.cpp:14:43: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
     printf( "'%s'\n", format_for( 5, 2, 1 ) );
                                           ^

C:\my\forums\so\081> _
```

So,

- Why does the above not compile with g++?
- How can the intent (hopefully evident from the code) be expressed?
- More generally, what are the rules for matching a call to declaration of variadic template function?

Comment: let alone everything, what's that line  ->  `{ {'%', 'f'+(0*args), ' '}..., {'%', 'f', 0} };` 0o

Comment: @AngelusMortis: It's an array initializer. With variadic argument expansion.

Comment: A parameter pack that is not the last function parameter is a non-deduced context. Is your intent for `args` to swallow everything but the last argument (which will be `last_arg`)?

Comment: That code is sooo above my brain :O

Comment: @Praetorian: yes. right on. oh, "non-deduced"! hm.

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14768951/241631 (Yakk's answer contains the solution you're looking for)

Comment: @Praetorian: Not sure. Basically yes a dupe, **but** I'm also very interested in how to do this correctly. That includes *expanding* the args without the last one.

Comment: Is there any super-special thing you need to do with the last one, or is it just the `' '` vs `'\0'` difference?

Comment: @T.C.: Just that difference,yes. At least in this concrete case. Let's not generalize needlessly. :)

Comment: Oh, transform to index sequence, probably. I'm as dumb as usual. Hrmf.

Comment: Just realized that the args will all be of the same type, so the order doesn't matter for generating specifiers.

Answer (score 5):

`Args` appears in a non-deduced context. In this case, that makes it being deduced as [the the empty pack](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#3).

If you want to extract the last argument but maintain usual deduction rules, you can write a simple helper:

```
template <typename U>
constexpr U&& last(U&& u) {return std::forward<U>(u);}
template <typename U, typename... T>
constexpr decltype(auto) last(U&&, T&&... t) {return last(std::forward<T>(t)...);}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee1e7e24851232e7).

> More generally, what are the rules for matching a call to declaration of variadic template function?

Those are pretty verbose, but function parameter packs that are *not* trailing will generally either be deduced to empty ones or yield a deduction failure.

---

In your particular case, try `index_sequence`s:

```
template <class... Args, std::size_t... indices>
auto format_for( std::index_sequence<indices...>, Args... args )
{
    auto tup = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    using Specifier = char const [3];
    static Specifier const s[] = { {'%', (char)('f'+(0*std::get<indices>(tup))), ' '}..., {'%', 'f', 0} };
    int last_arg = std::get<sizeof...(Args)-1>(tup);
    return s;
}

template <class... Args>
auto format_for( Args&&... args ) {
    return format_for(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)-1>{}, 
                      std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

…and hope that the compiler optimizes well - [Demo 2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17445bacf831db6a). Or go down the cheeky road:

```
template <class... Args, std::size_t... indices>
auto format_for( std::index_sequence<indices...>, Args... args )
{
    using Specifier = char const [3];
    static Specifier const s[] = {
      {'%', (char)(indices == sizeof...(Args)-1?
       'f' : 'f'+(0*args)), ' '}... };
    int last_arg = last(args...); // As before
    return s;
}

template <class... Args>
auto format_for( Args&&... args ) {
    return format_for(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{}, 
                      std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Demo 3](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f86a56f5839206d2).

Comment: Thanks, very nice. But I'm not so much interested in the type of the last arg. I'm interested in using the n-1 first args to generate n-1 format specifiers in a raw string constant. Is that possible?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So you want to be able to use both the first n-1 elements as one sole pack and the last element on its own?

Comment: Yes, I think that's it. See the out-commented code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Hmm, your sample code is both weird and ugly :D. Anyway, I added some approaches.