# Parameter with non-deduced type after parameter pack

Tags: c++, g++, variadic-templates, clang++, c++17

There is different behaviour in *clang++* and *g++* for the next program:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template< std::size_t index, typename type >
struct ref { type & value; };

template< std::size_t index, typename type >
type && get(ref< index, type > const & r)
{
    return std::forward< type >(r.value);
}

template< typename F, typename ...types, std::size_t ...indices >
decltype(auto) apply_inverse(F & f, types &... values, std::index_sequence< indices... >)
{
    struct : ref< indices, types >... {} refs{{values}...};
    constexpr std::size_t top = sizeof...(indices) - 1;
    return std::forward< F >(f)(get< top - indices >(refs)...);
}

template< typename F, typename ...types >
decltype(auto) apply_inverse(F && f, types &&... values)
{
    return apply_inverse< F, types... >(f, values..., std::index_sequence_for< types... >{});
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto const print = [] (auto const &... value) -> std::ostream & { return (std::cout << ... << value); };
    apply_inverse(print, 1, 2, 3) << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/g/mS4fjK).

It just tries to revert the arguments passed and applies some function to them.

For *G++* it compiles fine, but for *clang++* (even from trunk) it gives the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'apply_inverse'

I think the reason is the fact, that in upper overloading there is a parameter after parameter pack in the function prototype. But types for all the arguments in arguments pack are explicitly specified.

Is it right for compiler to accept the code?

Comment: [MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ff90251ab8e0bd3)

Comment: Reduced further: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82f3d4b32bcffe56

Comment: @T.C. Isn't clang right in this case, because of how parameters packs work?

Comment: I don't think it's specified, but the g++ approach to let all explicitly specified type arguments be consumed by the first (non-deduced here) parameter pack from a parameter declaration list doesn't sound reasonable. On the other hand, a non-deduced parameter can be provided explicitly, so... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

It was not specified exactly what version of Clang refused the code above.

But at this moment Clang 12 accepts it, as well as GCC and MSVC:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qMc9fKTEf

So the code is perfectly legal.