# need to call a function at periodic time intervals in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, timer

I am writing a program in c++ where I need to call a function at periodic time intervals, say every 10ms or so. I've never done anything related to time or clocks in c++, is this a quick and easy problem or one of those where there is no neat solution?

Thanks!

Comment: `<chrono>` has this support.

Answer (score 35):

To complete the question, the code from @user534498 can be easily adapted to have the periodic tick interval. 
It's just needed to determinate the next start time point at the beginning of the timer thread loop and `sleep_until` that time point after executing the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

void timer_start(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval)
{
  std::thread([func, interval]()
  { 
    while (true)
    { 
      auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(interval);
      func();
      std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
    }
  }).detach();
}

void do_something()
{
  std::cout << "I am doing something" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  timer_start(do_something, 1000);
  while (true)
    ;
}
```

Comment: This is the right approach, just beware that `func()` must finish before the end of `sleep_until`!

Comment: @florgeng, what if the function do_something takes parameter?

Comment: @EdisonLo You can bind the arguments using std::bind to the function. eg.:`do_something2(int i)` and you want to call it with i=25 then call `timer_start(std::bind(do_something2,25),1000)`

Comment: This would work well even if `func()` takes more than `interval` milliseconds (it will not sleep), however g++ < 4.9.3 hangs forever (https://stackoverflow.com/q/51755266).

Comment: Note that this solution may drift if `sleep_until` is not perfectly accurate, or the jump/`now()` computation takes time.

Comment: You can avoid drift (well not avoid, so much as account for) by incrementing a target time, and wait for that. This code keeps recalculating the target time based on now(), so it's going to drift by how long it takes between sleeps. (Which is usually fine.)

Answer (score 23):

A simple timer can be implemented as follows,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

void timer_start(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval)
{
    std::thread([func, interval]() {
        while (true)
        {
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        }
    }).detach();
}


void do_something()
{
    std::cout << "I am doing something" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    timer_start(do_something, 1000);

    while(true);
}
```

This simple solution does not offer a way to stop the timer. The timer will keep running until the program exited.

Comment: @user534498 Unfortunately your solution won't do what he asked. It will execute `func` with `interval` delay between calls. It won't execute `func` every `interval`. If the `func` can take some variable time to run the times of start will vary also.

Answer (score 1):

If you're coding with Visual C++, you could add a timer element to the form you want to call a periodic function (here it's called my form is `MainForm`, and my timer `MainTimer`). Add a call to the tick event in the "Events". The designer will add such line in your .h file:

```
this->MainTimer->Enabled = true;
this->MainTimer->Interval = 10;
this->MainTimer->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MainForm::MainTimer_Tick);
```

Then, at each interval (specified in ms), the application will call this function

```
private: System::Void MainTimer_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
   /// Enter your periodic code there
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into threading:

Here's a time interval controlled function implemented in C, using pthread.h, it should be a simple port to C++.
[Executing a function at specific intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463621/executing-a-function-at-specific-intervals)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you would be doing on per interval - displaying time/ticker or something else at specific location of screen/form. Or you may need to send regular data to some connected machine (over socket or pipe). Do you really need 10 millisecond precision?

Depending on requirement, especially the precision requirement, you may have dedicated thread to do *'something*', then wait and do same thing again. Or, on Windows, you may use `SetTimer` that would trigger `WM_TIMER` event on each interval (it wouldn't require thread). You may also use waitable timer, multimedia timer etc.

At last, but quite important - Do you need platform and compiler compatibility? Meaning that, which OS you would be using, or you need platform independent? What compiler features you are looking for (C++11, C++14 or pre C++11).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I didn't find a design simpler than that.

You could, make a class that owns both a thread, and a `weak_ptr` to itself,
to be a "holder" that the callable can see it safely, because the callable
will still exists even if the object is destructed. You don't want a dangling pointer.

```
template<typename T>
struct IntervalRepeater {
    using CallableCopyable = T;
private:
    weak_ptr<IntervalRepeater<CallableCopyable>> holder;
    std::thread theThread;

    IntervalRepeater(unsigned int interval,
            CallableCopyable callable): callable(callable), interval(interval) {}

    void thread() {
        weak_ptr<IntervalRepeater<CallableCopyable>> holder = this->holder;
        theThread = std::thread([holder](){
            // Try to strongify the pointer, to make it survive this loop iteration,
            //    and ensure that this pointer is valid, if not valid, end the loop.
            while (shared_ptr<IntervalRepeater<CallableCopyable>> ptr = holder.lock()) {
                auto x = chrono::steady_clock::now() + chrono::milliseconds(ptr->interval);
                ptr->callable();
                this_thread::sleep_until(x);
            }
        });
    }

public:
    const CallableCopyable callable;
    const unsigned int interval;

    static shared_ptr<IntervalRepeater<T>> createIntervalRepeater(unsigned int interval,
            CallableCopyable callable) {
        std::shared_ptr<IntervalRepeater<CallableCopyable>> ret =
                shared_ptr<IntervalRepeater<CallableCopyable>>(
                        new IntervalRepeater<CallableCopyable>(interval, callable));
        ret->holder = ret;
        ret->thread();

        return ret;
    }

    ~IntervalRepeater() {
        // Detach the thread before it is released.
        theThread.detach();
    }

};

void beginItWaitThenDestruct() {
    auto repeater = IntervalRepeater<function<void()>>::createIntervalRepeater(
            1000, [](){ cout << "A second\n"; });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3700));
}

int main() {
    beginItWaitThenDestruct();
    // Wait for another 2.5 seconds, to test whether there is still an effect of the object
    //   or no.
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2500));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old post but I found a really easy solution to this and I would like to 
share it:

the solution is to

```
#include "unistd.h"
```

and use the function which is included in the above library,

```
usleep(int)
```

for example this would call a function every 3000 microseconds

```
int main() {

    int sleep_time = 3000;
    while(true) { 

          usleep(sleep_time);

          call function;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I used it as well for serial and parallel codes and works in both cases!

Answer (score 0):

I made myself an async system. It should not be confused with `std::async`. Since it is custom made, I have full control over the timeline, so I can add, edit, remove, append, etc tasks. Mainly it runs in a single thread and guarantees safety between context switches, but also has support for multi-thread syncing. Try to make your own async system, from my experience I would say it's worth it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that getting the time point also take some time, the following code (which I have written without any fancy-schmancy shenanigans) is a bit more accurate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void func() {
    std::cout << "This function does something!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::chrono::seconds one_sec(1);
    std::chrono::time_point starting_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while(true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(starting_time + one_sec);
        func();
        starting_time += one_sec;
    }
}
```

Of course, you can also put everything into a thread:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void func() {
    std::cout << "This function does something!" << std::endl;
}

void threadfunc() {
    std::chrono::seconds one_sec(1);
    std::chrono::time_point starting_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while(true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(starting_time + one_sec);
        func();
        starting_time += one_sec;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread periodicFunctionThread(threadfunc);
    periodicFunctionThread.join(); //Probably you would use detach, this is only for demonstration purposes.
}
```