# Stopping a periodic thread-thing in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, intervals

So I have this function which is behaving like the setInterval function in JS. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43373364/7976388).
I am currently trying to change it so it can be stopped. I do not fully understand the behavior of this code.

```
void setInterval(function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval) {
  thread([func, interval]() {
    while (1) {
      auto x = chrono::steady_clock::now() + chrono::milliseconds(interval);
      func();
      this_thread::sleep_until(x);
    }
  }).detach();
}
```

I tried it like this:

```
void setInterval(function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval, bool &b) {
  thread([func, interval, *b]() {
    while (*b) {
      auto x = chrono::steady_clock::now() + chrono::milliseconds(interval);
      func();
      this_thread::sleep_until(x);
    }
  }).detach();
}
```

(this won't compile), and in main calling it like this:

```
bool B;
setInterval(myFunction,1000,B);
```

I was expecting that if I change the B variable to false, then the thread in setInterval function stops, but I haven't managed to reach my goal like this. Any idead/suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please *always* provide a [mcve] that other people can test for themselves.

Comment: Does this code actually compile?

Comment: My code does not

Comment: Well, what are the compiler errors you are getting then?

Comment: @SótanyiBálint What is the meaning of `*b`, when the type of `b` is `bool&`? It is **not** a pointer, so why are you trying to dereference it?

Comment: I thought it is a pointer actually

Comment: @SótanyiBálint Why would you think so? Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). References are covered in those.

Comment: I am learning now from Accelerated C++, but sometimes i get confused. Maybe because I used JS until now and I am still thinking in that way

Comment: @Sótanyi Bálint C++ is *not* like JS (even if the syntax may sometimes seem similar). Forget *all* you know about JS when writing C++ code - they are *very* different languages.

Comment: Do you have any ideas regarding my question? Or a different way to solve this problem?

Comment: @SótanyiBálint "_Do you have any ideas regarding my question?_" Please re-read my initial comment (reading the compilation errors, would be a great place to start, as well), and act accordingly: don't try to dereference something, that is not a pointer.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Use `&b` to capture by reference, though `bool` requires synchronization and can't safely be accessed synchronously. `std::atomic_bool` would work. You should also consider rather `detach` really is what you want to do. Using `detach` is often a sign of poor design is may cause you problems in the future. You will usually want to keep a handle on your thread and `join` it to know when it's finished stopping.

Comment: You can do it really expressively if you're already using a framework or engine with an event loop and timer mechanism (which, in the case of JavaScript, is done for you). If you aren't, then you can't. Shrug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I didn't find a design simpler than that.

You could, make a class that owns both a thread, and a `weak_ptr` to itself,
to be a "holder" that the callable can see it safely, because the callable
will still exists even if the object is destructed. You don't want a dangling pointer.

```
template<typename T>
struct IntervalRepeater {
    using CallableCopyable = T;
private:
    weak_ptr<IntervalRepeater<CallableCopyable>> holder;
    std::thread theThread;

    IntervalRepeater(unsigned int interval,
            CallableCopyable callable): callable(callable), interval(interval) {}

    void thread() {
        weak_ptr<IntervalRepeater<CallableCopyable>> holder = this->holder;
        theThread = std::thread([holder](){
            // Try to strongify the pointer, to make it survive this loop iteration,
            //    and ensure that this pointer is valid, if not valid, end the loop.
            while (shared_ptr<IntervalRepeater<CallableCopyable>> ptr = holder.lock()) {
                auto x = chrono::steady_clock::now() + chrono::milliseconds(ptr->interval);
                ptr->callable();
                this_thread::sleep_until(x);
            }
        });
    }

public:
    const CallableCopyable callable;
    const unsigned int interval;

    static shared_ptr<IntervalRepeater<T>> createIntervalRepeater(unsigned int interval,
            CallableCopyable callable) {
        std::shared_ptr<IntervalRepeater<CallableCopyable>> ret =
                shared_ptr<IntervalRepeater<CallableCopyable>>(
                        new IntervalRepeater<CallableCopyable>(interval, callable));
        ret->holder = ret;
        ret->thread();

        return ret;
    }

    ~IntervalRepeater() {
        // Detach the thread before it is released.
        theThread.detach();
    }

};

void beginItWaitThenDestruct() {
    auto repeater = IntervalRepeater<function<void()>>::createIntervalRepeater(
            1000, [](){ cout << "A second\n"; });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3700));
}

int main() {
    beginItWaitThenDestruct();
    // Wait for another 2.5 seconds, to test whether there is still an effect of the object
    //   or no.
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2500));
    return 0;
}
```

C++ is not JavaScript, but C++ can apply most programming paradigms in different languages.

Comment: The trouble is that this code must also take on the responsibility covered by part of the JavaScript runtime engine, making the "user-space" end result necessarily more verbose than the JS code equivalent. In short, it's not a fair test.