# Run time of code in open cv?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I am working on open CV.The code is written in c++.I want to find out the time taken by the program to execute.its just a basic question.

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do that (see [Easily measure elapsed time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time)). A simple approach is the following:

```
#include <time>

void main()
{
    clock_t start_time = clock();
    // Do something
    clock_t end_time = clock();
    float time_in_seconds = (end_time-start_time)/(float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

Comment: be careful, this only works correctly for single-core systems.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- profile your program, that means run it in a special setting which will modify and/or monitor your code with timing probe and report statistics about how much time is spent in functions / lines of codes. Since you're using Visual Studio, depending on your version you could try [its integrated profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx) or try something like Intel VTune or AMD CodeAnalyst
- manually add code to take time measurements at specific points in your code. In C++ and windows, an easy and accurate way of doing that is `QueryPerformanceCounter` from `<windows.h>`. It's more accurate than `clock` and less accurate than CPU's performance counters, but these are harder to exploit in a multi-core system.

Example for second option:

```
// init
#include <Windows.h>
LARGE_INTEGER freq;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
double milliseconds = 1000.0 / freq.QuadPart;

// timed execution
LARGE_INTEGER start, stop;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
call_your_function();
QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
double time_in_ms = (stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) * milliseconds;
```