# Handling void assignment in C++ generic programming

Tags: c++

I have C++ code that wraps an arbitrary lambda and returns the result of the lambda.

```
template <typename F>
auto wrapAndRun(F fn) -> decltype(F()) {
    // foo();
    auto result = fn();
    // bar();
    return result;
}
```

This works unless `F` returns `void` (`error: variable has incomplete type 'void'`). I thought of using a `ScopeGuard` to run `bar`, but I don't want `bar` to run if `fn` throws. Any ideas?

P.S. I found out later there's [a proposal to fix this inconsistency](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0146r1.html).

Comment: which version of C++, 14 or 17?

Comment: This is for a personal project, so even c++2x is fine.

Comment: Had the same problem before, same solution applies. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468397/a-timer-for-arbitrary-functions It's just C++11 though, could probably be modernized.

Comment: Have you looked into `std::invoke`? Looks like exactly that you need

Comment: @SemyonBurov how will ```std::invoke``` help me here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another trick might be to exploit the comma operator, something like:

```
struct or_void {};

template<typename T>
T&& operator,( T&& x, or_void ){ return std::forward<T>(x); }

template <typename F>
auto wrapAndRun(F fn) -> decltype(fn()) {
    // foo();
    auto result = ( fn(), or_void() );
    // bar();
    return decltype(fn())(result);
}
```

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Overloading the comma operator is one of those things that a decent chunk of the C++ community (self included) will just tell you never to do. Yes, I understood the idea, but this is 100%, dead on, the kind of black magic overloading that so, so many people and style guides have recommended against. If there was really, really no other way it might be worth considering but there's 4 solutions already here that are all preferable.

Comment: @NirFriedman respectfully, I disagree; first, the comma operator *is* used in existing widely used libraries (boost, Eigen to cite the first that come to my mind), so claiming that *everybody* say to *never* use it, is simply false. Second, the reasons people should (rightfully) avoid overloading the comma operator do not apply here, you can easily make this safe.

Comment: third, we don't know the final aim and scope of the OP code; he might just need a technical solution to a problem, buried in implementation details. This answer is a valid solution to the OP question, period. Afaik, downvoting it just because it 'feels' bad to you goes against the meaning of voting.

Comment: You're entitled to disagree, and I'm entitled to downvote. It's a solution I would never recommend to anyone who needs to ask for a solution to OP's problem in the first place, put it this way. I'm allowed to downvote a solution I would never recommend, especially when there are multiple answers already up that I would recommend, aren't I?

I'm obviously not the only one who feels this way about the comma operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602112/when-to-overload-the-comma-operator.

Comment: Beyond that, it also doesn't correctly handle functions that return reference type (easily fixable), and it also doubly invalidates RVO, i.e. when I run this code there are 2 extraneous destructor calls, as opposed to either one or zero found in most other solutions here.

Comment: @NirFriedman uhm, the very answer you linked to in your comment mentions that comma can be used as a metaprogramming technique (as is sometimes used indeed) among other legit uses. Frankly, I believe guidelines exist (or should exist) as a means to comunicate the *reasons* why something is bad, not to sell dogmas about one should always/never do. Regarding, the downvote issue, I think the voting mechanism already allow establishing a hierarchy of answers; if I read SO help and meta posts  correctly, downvotes should be reserved to non useful or wrong answers only.

Comment: regarding the reference and RVO issue, these are solvable and have nothing to do with the answer idea ... anyway, it seems I triggered a vote war :) ...so I'll stop here

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes If you solve both issues I'll remove the downvote, how's that as a peace offering :-).

Answer (score 25):

You can write a simple wrapper class that handles this part of it:

```
template <class T>
struct CallAndStore {
    template <class F>
    CallAndStore(F f) : t(f()) {}
    T t;
    T get() { return std::forward<T>(t); }
};
```

And specialize:

```
template <>
struct CallAndStore<void> {
    template <class F>
    CallAndStore(F f) { f(); }
    void get() {}
};
```

You can improve usability with a small factory function:

```
template <typename F>
auto makeCallAndStore(F&& f) -> CallAndStore<decltype(std::declval<F>()())> {
    return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

Then use it.

```
template <typename F>
auto wrapAndRun(F fn) {
    // foo();
    auto&& result = makeCallAndStore(std::move(fn));
    // bar();
    return result.get();
}
```

Edit: with the `std::forward` cast inside `get`, this also seems to handle returning a reference from a function correctly.

Comment: I like your solution better but are there some limitations on returned type based on fact it must be stored in your case?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the limitation? It just needs to be movable (let me add a std::move).

Comment: Maybe not limitations but differences, for example I am not sure destructor of `T` can be avoided in your case as RVO cannot be applied

Comment: @Slava That's a good point. An alternative would be write a function instead, `callAndReturn`, that takes two lambdas, with two overloads. Call the first lambda, store the result if non-void type, then call the second. This scales well (better than other answers) if `bar()` is actually a standin for a few lines of code.

Comment: You can also use functions to do the type deduction without having to wait for type deduction for constructors

Comment: @Curious Yeah, In that case though I'd want to be sure it doesn't trigger any more un-elided moves of the return type. I've already introduced one extra move here, definitely don't want to introduce another.

Comment: @NirFriedman you don't need any of that, even with C++14, https://wandbox.org/permlink/EaThZXFeddyi4oEv Also the `decltype(F())` could be improved for the same reason `result_of` is deprecated.  See how I get the return type in the linked code

Comment: @Curious Nice trick, I agree that's strictly better. Feel free to edit the answer to include your improvements (and delete my comment about deduction guides).

Comment: @Curious I added your improvements to my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 22):

The new C++17 `if constexpr` addition may be helpful here. You can choose whether to return `fn()`'s result at compile-time:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename F>
auto wrapAndRun(F fn) -> decltype(fn())
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(fn()), void>)
    {
        foo();
        fn();
        bar();
    }
    else
    {
        foo();
        auto result = fn();
        bar();
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you said C++20 is an option as well, you could also make use of concepts, putting a constraint on the function:

```
template <typename F>
  requires requires (F fn) { { fn() } -> void }
void wrapAndRun(F fn)
{
    foo();
    fn();
    bar();
}

template <typename F>
decltype(auto) wrapAndRun(F fn)
{
    foo();
    auto result = fn();
    bar();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can this be done without repeating the calls to `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: @NirFriedman Yes, but I have the opinion that the trade-off is not good. After all, this code isn't suffering because of repetition, and is simple enough.

Comment: Sorry, what's the trade-off exactly? Also, it's an assumption that there are literally two function calls. In the OP's case or in the general case, there may be more code there, that the user may or may not feel like factoring out into a function.

Comment: @NirFriedman: if there's more code there, he should probably refactor that out, into `foo()` and `bar()`

Comment: @MooingDuck Err, why? Somewhere you have to have code, you know, it can't all be function calls. Such a factoring may be the right call, maybe even most of the time, but perhaps not all of the time. A solution that basically forces you to factor out into `foo` and `bar` is worse than one that doesn't (all other things being equal, of course).

Comment: @NirFriedman it could be refactored to lambdas inside the function template.

Comment: Main purpose of generic code is to avoid code duplicate. Write duplicated code in generic - what could be worse?

Answer (score 6):

You can have a look at the ScopeGuard by Alexandrescu: [ScopeGuard.h](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/ScopeGuard.h) It executes code only when there was no exception.

```
template<class Fn>
decltype(auto) wrapAndRun(Fn&& f) {
  foo();
  SCOPE_SUCCESS{ bar(); }; //Only executed at scope exit when there are no exceptions.
  return std::forward<Fn>(f)();
}
```

So in case of no errors, the execution order is: 1. foo(), 2. f(), 3. bar(). And in case of an exception the order is: 1. foo(), 2. f()

Comment: This is interesting. I didn't realize it was possible to write `uncaught_exceptions` (notice the s) prior to 17 in user space; this is a prerequisite for things like SCOPE_SUCCESS. Nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

Solution with SFINAE, the idea is to make internally a void function actually return int - hopefully the compiler will optimize this away. On outside `wrapAndRun` will return the same type as a wrapped function.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e84ff8f74b3b6051

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F>
auto wrapAndRun1(F fn) -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::result_of_t<F()>, void>, std::result_of_t<F()>> {
    return fn();
}


template <typename F>
auto wrapAndRun1(F fn) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::result_of_t<F()>, void>, int> {
    fn();
    return 0;
}

template <typename F>
auto wrapAndRun(F fn) -> std::result_of_t<F()> {
    // foo();
    [[maybe_unused]] auto result = wrapAndRun1(fn);    
    // bar();        
    if constexpr (std::is_void_v<std::result_of_t<F()>>)
        return;
    else
        return result;
}

int main()
{
    wrapAndRun([] { std::cout << "with return \n"; return 0; });
    wrapAndRun([] { std::cout << "no return \n"; });
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to run `bar()` in case `fn()` return type is void

Comment: Not sure why the top enable_if seems to have some repetition? I think in any case the answer would benefit from writing a separate `returns_void` trait. Though, the significant disadvantage here is that you have to repeat `foo` and `bar` in two places (and indeed one was already forgotten).

Comment: Code repetition is ugly and I do not think that is a good solution if can be avoided.

Comment: @Nir Friedman - I have removed duplications. I think it looks quite nice now.

Comment: @marcinj Sorry to be a pedant, but I'm a bit concerned that when the passed function returns void, the wrapper still returns `0`. This might be "good enough" for the OP but I feel like it's not optimal; could prevent catching a mistake at compile time.

Comment: @Nir Friedman I understand, I have updated answer - now it returns the same type as the wrapped function has.

Comment: If you are already using `if constexpr`, how about this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/705050e725bc72e9? Looks pretty good! Though this still doesn't handle functions returning reference types. Either way, have an upvote :-).

Answer (score 2):

The most convenient way to do solve this problem is to wrap `void` in a type that you can actually use, along with a version of `std::invoke` that converts `void` to this regular type. Using [my void library](https://github.com/brevzin/void/) (C++17):

```cpp
template <typename F>
auto wrapAndRun(F fn) -> vd::wrap_void<std::invoke_result_t<F&>>
    // foo();
    auto result = vd::invoke(fn);
    // bar();
    return result;
}
```

If `fn()` isn't `void`, this does the same thing that it did before. Returns whatever type. If `fn()` *is* `void`, then `result` has type `vd::Void`, which is just some empty type.

This is convenient because you put all the special-case void handling into one spot (in this case, the library) and then the rest of your code looks... normal. You don't have to write any bespoke special cases for each use, and you don't have to reorganize the logic of your code based on the solution you choose - you can still call `foo()` and `bar()` before and after `fn` just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty awkward and not extendable solution but very short and simple and it supports [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) which could be significant for some return types:

```
template <typename F>
auto wrapAndRun(F fn) -> decltype(F()) {
    // foo();
    char c;
    auto runner = std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(bar)>( &c, bar );
    try {
        return fn();
    }
    catch( ... ) {
        runner.release();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: For RVO: I'd misread a key part of the code. RVO should work fine.

Comment: What is RVO...?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Return Value Optimization.