# Measuring time in a multithreaded C++ application

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

I'm writing an application using C++ and OpenMP and I want to reliably (and correctly) measure time of execution of parts of it. I have reviewed a few options (Windows,  TDM-GCC x64 4.8.1):

1. `omp_get_wproc` and `clock` seem to do the job but documentation (in direct contradiction to actual behavior) says that they measure total time resources consumed by given process (that is, e.g. one second with two working threads counts as two seconds). The "correct" behavior is *not* what I want,
2. `time`/`difftime` don't have enough resolution,
3. `GetProcessTime` (WinAPI) does what clock should do and is platform-specific,
4. `QueryPerformanceCounter` (WinAPI) seems to be the way to go but is platform-specific,
5. C++11 `high_resolution_clock` works ok but it's a part of a new standard.

My question, primarily, is: how do people doing scientific computing do this, and why do it that way? And, is the behavior of `clock` a bug in my implementation of standard library or a too popular misconception?

EDIT:
Small explanation: I'm a bit hesitant to use C++11 because I'll probably run my code on a cluster with somewhat old software.

Comment: W.r.t the new standard and `high_resolution_clock` is the code required to be compatible with C++03?

Comment: You could also take a look at boost::chrono, it provides a somewhat convenient wrapper for whatever happens to be currently available.

Comment: right, I've actually taken a look at boost::chrono to find that for Windows it actually uses QueryPerformanceCounter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention [`boost::chrono`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono.html). Same as C++11 `chrono`, but works with C++03 compiler.

Also, I cannot understand your hesitation about C++11. We are almost in 2015, and C++11 is not that new. It is even not the most recent standard. So, `#include <chrono>` is a way to go.

Note however, that `chrono` is somewhat broken in Visual Studio 2013 Standard library implementation. I, personally, use `std::chrono` everywhere and swap it to `boost::chrono` via conditional `defines` and `typedef`s. Hope they'll fix it in Visual Studio Next.

Comment: Oh yes, Boost is probably an even better choice than doing the system calls yourself.  At least if Boost already is a dependency of your project.

Comment: @5gon12eder Fair enough. Even worse. Actually, to use boost you would need two compiled libs: `boost_chrono` and `boost_system`. Though, if we're talking about cross-platform threading with C++03 we, probably, already have `boost::thread` and `boost::system` as dependencies, so `boost::chrono` fits just well here.

Answer (score 3):

Copied directly from my current research project:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <type_traits>

/** @brief Best available clock. */
using clock_type = typename std::conditional<
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady,
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
  std::chrono::steady_clock>::type;
```

We want to measure wall time, not user-space CPU cycles to be fair and account for the multi-threading overhead as well.  Unfortunately, many implementations define `high_resolution_clock` as an alias for `real_time_clock` which would spoil our results in case the system time is adjusted during our measurements.

Yes, `std::chrono` is a C++11 feature but if this is research as you say, what stops you from using the most modern compiler?  You won't need your code to compile on the most weird platform that might exist somewhere in some dusty cellar of a customer.  Anyway, if you just cannot have C++11, you can easily implement these clocks yourself.  They are (at least in GNU libstdc++) just thin wrappers around [`clock_gettime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html).

Comment: On this typeswitch : Typically `high_resolution_clock` is a typedef for either `system_clock` or `steady_clock`. So to trace that `std::conditional` if the `is_steady` part is true, then you pick the `high_resolution_clock` which is (a typedef to) the `steady_clock`. If it's false then you pick the `steady_clock` again. Just use `steady_clock` from the beginning ...

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou While this might “typically” be the case, the standard does not mandate it. `std::chrono::{system,steady,high_resolution}_clock` *may* be implemented as three different clocks. That's not to say that `steady_clock` isn't a decent choice in practice.

Comment: N.B you should also find a way, for you and users of your code, to avoid non-portably mixing time points of different clocks (if ever this type switch acquires a meaning, it'll behave differently on different platforms)