# Easily measure elapsed time for methods

Tags: c++, templates, methods, benchmarking

I want to measure the execution time of methods and found the following Topic:

[Easily measure elapsed time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time)

There exists an answer for measuring the function execution time with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::milliseconds>
struct measure
{
    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static typename TimeT::rep execution(F func, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast< TimeT> 
                            (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        return duration.count();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << measure<>::execution(functor(dummy)) << std::endl;
}
```

Is it possible to use this code for method measurement? How can i change the template types to pass a method and an object like

```
measure<>::execution(object, method);
```

or better

```
measure<>::execution(object.method(param));
```

By now, i have the following result:

```
struct measure
{
    template<class T, typename R>
    static R execution(T& obj, R(T::*func)())
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        R result = (obj.*func)();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>
                            (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
        return result;
    }
};
```

But i don't know how to pass Args and use it as shown in the example above. I have to execute

```
measure::execution(obj, method);
```

Comment: have you tried anything? where's your attempt?

Comment: note that arguments are evaluated first, so `object.method(param)` won't work.

Comment: I've found it useful to make a `timer` class that initializes a `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>` (or other clock) in its constructor, and in its destructor take the current time and display how much time has elapsed.

Comment: @TobiasBraun, You can use `std::mem_fn` to wrap your pointer-to-member into a callable that can be used with the first version of `measure<>::execution`. The call would look like `measure<>::execution(std::mem_fn(ptr_to_member),object);`