# Calculating Running Time of Binary Search

Tags: c++

The following Binary Search program is returning a running time of `0` milliseconds using `GetTickCount()` no matter how big the search item is set in the given list of values.

Is there any other way to get the running time for comparison?

Here's the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        long int i = 1, max = 10000000;
        long int *data = new long int[max];
        long int initial = 1;
        long int final = max, mid, loc = -5;
        for(i = 1; i<=max; i++)
        {
            data[i] = i;
        }

        int range = final - initial + 1;
        long int search_item = 8800000;

        cout<<"Search Item :- "<<search_item<<"\n";

        cout<<"-------------------Binary Search-------------------\n";
        long int start = GetTickCount();
        cout<<"Start Time : "<<start<<"\n";

        while(initial<=final)
        {
            mid=(initial+final)/2;

            if(data[mid]==search_item)
            {
                loc=mid;
                break;
            }

            if(search_item<data[mid])
                final=mid-1;

            if(search_item>data[mid])
                initial=mid+1;
        }
        long int end = GetTickCount();
        cout<<"End Time : "<<end<<"\n";
        cout << "time: " << double(end - start)<<" milliseconds \n";
        if(loc==-5)
            cout<<" Required number not found "<<endl;
        else
            cout<<" Required number is found at index "<<loc<<endl;
        return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You don't need a loop to fill in `data` or set `final`. The value of `final` can be easily calculated, and to initialize `data` you could use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

Comment: As for your problem, I recommend you count your curly-braces and check your indentation. Or remove that `return` statement (and rely on the implicit compiler-generated return statement) and run again to see what happens. Or simply step through the code in a debugger (which should have been your first instinct).

Comment: it is better to use DWORD as GetTickCount documentation mentioned

Comment: Edited Code to reflect final without loop but in case of using std::iota, I'm getting error 'iota' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: It is operating system specific. With C++11, see `<chrono>` header

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    // Some code...

    while (some_condition)
    {
        // Some more code...
        // Print timing result
        return 0;
    }
}
```

*That's* why your code prints zero time, you only do one iteration of the loop then you exit the program.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the clock_t object from the time.h header:

```
clock_t START, END;
        START = clock();
        **YOUR CODE GOES HERE**
        END = clock();
        float clocks = END - START;
        cout <<"running time : **" << clocks/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "** seconds" << endl;
```

CLOCKS_PER_SEC is a defined var to convert from clock ticks to seconds.

Comment: Used your approach but I'm still getting 0 seconds.

Comment: Write the code here below after you added the clock_t object, it may support us to help you. @ArunKumar

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx
This article says that result of **GetTickCount** will wrap to zero if you system runs for 49.7 days.

You can find here: [Easily measure elapsed time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time) how to measure time in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can use time.h header

and do something like this in your code :

```
clock_t Start, Stop;
double sec;

Start = clock();
//call your BS function
Stop = clock();

Sec = ((double) (Stop - Start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

and print the sec!

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Used your approach but I'm still getting 0 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of binary search is log2(N), it's about `23` for `N = 10000000`. 
I think its not enough to mesure in realtime scale and even `clock`.
In this case you should use `unsigned long long __rdtsc()`, that returns number of processor ticks from last reset. Put this before and after your binary search and place `cout << start;` after obtaining end time. Overwise time of output would be included.

There is also memory corruption around `data` array. Index in C runs from `0` to `size - 1`, so thereis no `data[max]` element.

And `delete [] data;` before calling return.