# C++ Cross platform nanosecond/microsecond timer?

Tags: c++, timer, game-engine, sdl-2

I am currently writing an SDL2 game engine, and it works pretty good so far, but there is one problem that SDL2 can't solve: a decent timer. Right now, it uses the default SDL2 timer stuff, but it has only millisecond support; and this is not very good for measuring FPS. The main problem is there is nothing in between 500FPS and 1000FPS, so it's one or the other. Obviously, potential gamers would want something a little more accurate than that, and getting accurate averages from those numbers is near impossible.

So my question is is there any clock libraries that can provide nanosecond/microsecond (Preferably the former) time measuring on Windows, Mac, and Linux? (Maybe even Android and iOS, but that is a bit of a stretch.)

If not, is there different libraries for each OS I could just `#if WINDOWS` or whatever to still get nanosecond/microsecond timing?

EDIT: A comment pointed out that some more information should be here, so I am using C++ 14, and will be on Mac and Linux as well. On Windows, I use MSVC (Visual Studio) and I plan to use XCode on Mac, and not too sure for Linux. Will as a friend.

Comment: Are you using `C++11` or later?

Comment: @MohitJain I added some more information to the post.

Comment: You can pick a solution from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time

Comment: Considering even the top gaming monitors top out at 144Hz having 500fps and 1000fps means you are leaving performance on the table.

Comment: "but it has only millisecond support" [...what?](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetPerformanceCounter)  Or does `SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency()` return `1000` on your platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been learning this new library lately and I think it might be able to help you out with your problem.

SFML
http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/

SFML/time
http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/system-time.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks fantastic! I'm looking into it right now, will report back soon.

Comment: After some looking into, it seems that this is a good library for me to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is about [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock)? Steady clock could be fine.

Comment: Upvoted.  SFML is limited to microsecond precision even when the underlying OS supports nanosecond precision.  `std::chrono` has superior functionality, portability and syntax (especially in C++14).

Answer (score 0):

GLFW has a timer that is pretty accurate. It is a millisecond timer as far as I know. GLFW is also a pretty decent library for window management and inputs such as mouse/keys/gamepads etc..

http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__time.html