# CPP Call slower than Python Interface Call

Tags: python, c++, windows, dll, caffe

The Github Page of Caffe contains a Windows Branch. I have taken this branch and created a Windows DLL. It is losely based on https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp.

The DLL works and outputs correct classification results. But it is 1.5-5 times slower than the pyCaffe interface. It is very interesting that the pyCaffe Interface takes around 1 second for four images using AlexNet on all computers tested. The DLL time ranges from 1.5 seconds to 2 seconds to 4 seconds.

We have measured the time before and after the loop (using [Easily measure elapsed time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time)) of

```
template <typename Dtype> Dtype Net<Dtype>::ForwardFromTo(int start, int end)
```

This function resides in https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/net.cpp and is called by the CPP and Python Code.

We have compiled Caffe as 32-bit programm without GPU support using Visual Studio 2013

Possible things we have checked so far.

- Compiler Optimizations
- The data
- OS and computer configurations (like CPU/Memory etc.)
- We have measured multiple times in one execution, such that the benchmark is more stable.
- We have also profiled the code using CodeXL but I could not find anything unusual, but that of course is a little bit vague.

Comment: What compiler optimisations did you enable ?

Comment: What exactly do you get in the profiling data? Where is it spending time?

Answer (score 1):

We concluded following: Caffe uses GLog. GLog has Fatal Warning which may look like this

```
CHECK(a<=b) << "a must be bigger than b";
```

These warnings let the program crash and are hardly catchable. For that we have created a class to replace GLog. It is fairly simple and uses std::stringstream. Google has done something clever. Whenever the condition is true, the right hand side is not evaluated.

https://github.com/google/glog/blob/de6149ef8e67b064a433a8b88924fa9f606ad5d5/src/windows/glog/logging.h#L569

They solved it using the (void) 0. We missed that part. When I wanted to post the profiling data here, I recognised that some time is lost due to the << operator. We started looking at the profiling data closer and increased the number of function calls, such that every number gets a little bit bigger and clearer. This then has lead us to the solution.