# Limits on optimization reordering C++ function execution

Tags: c++, gcc

My understanding is that in the C++ specification the compiler can an reorder statements so long as the input/output order and information remain unchanged.

I'm a little bit confused how this interacts with system function calls or even try/catch statements.

Suppose we have 3 functions and each can throw an exception. If the compiler can reorder their execution in a try block doesn't the output change?

Even more simply can we rely on the fact that system calls must be in order? Under what conditions can the ordering of these calls happen? Is there a way to get GCC treat a pure C++ function as a system call or enforce function ordering?

In general the answer of what the compiler understands/sees and thus is allowed to optimize away is pretty ambiguous.

Comment: It does not reorder function calls. It may reorder inside continuous instructions, that is why their bounds are named "sequence points"

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order ; too dense, didn't read: basically the compiler has to pretend that what you have written has executed in the order written, especially externally visible stuff like propagating exceptions

Comment: the compiler applies only those omptimizations that it can proove to not alter the observable behavior. If rearranging something would alter the output, then its not an allowed optimization

Comment: This question should be re-opened, there are multiple inconsistencies in the answers vs answers in other questions.

Comment: what inconsistencies do you refer to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190364/is-it-legal-for-a-c-optimizer-to-reorder-calls-to-clock

Comment: Read the rule again: If reordering three functions in a try block changes the output then the “as if” rule doesn’t allow it.

Comment: dont get me wrong, I am just one click away from reopening, but I am still convincend that the dupe target is the best fit for your question in its generality. The question you link is not inconsistent with the as-if rule, but the answers there explain why the reording observed there is not a contradiction to the as if rule. It still is the so called "as if rule" that sets the limits for compiler optimizations

Comment: @273K: if changing the order of function calls doesn’t change observable behaviour then function calls can be reordered.

Comment: What even is "observable behavior" is ambiguous as obviously outputting the time between reordered system calls will result in different outputs.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572817/timing-vs-the-as-if-rule

Comment: ok, now I see the inconsistency in answers (not in the one you link, but in the one you link vs the one I just linked ;)

Comment: @FourierFlux C++ Draft Standard: [\[intro.abstract#6\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#6) defines: _"observable behavior"_

Comment: @FourierFlux - Timing is not an observable behavior, as the language doesn't specify how fast the code should run.

Comment: But when it interacts with the OS it is observable. IMO it is a glaring failure to allow code to be repositioned between opaque function calls.

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is that in the C++ specification the compiler can an reorder statements so long as the input/output order and information remain unchanged.

The compiler can do anything that produces a binary that will have the same observable behavior as the standard specified the program to have on the abstract machine.

If the order of evaluations does not affect the specified observable behavior, then it doesn't matter in which order corresponding machine instructions are emitted. In fact no directly one-to-one corresponding instructions to an evaluation must exist at all.

> Suppose we have 3 functions and each can throw an exception. If the compiler can reorder their execution in a try block doesn't the output change?

Then the compiler cannot reorder the calls to these functions. But note that the function calls don't even have to exist in the binary produced by the compiler either. For example the compiler could have inlined all of them and then applied optimizations to the resulting larger function. Or the compiler might figure out that because of what exactly is written in the functions that observable behavior can't change if the call order is changed. Then the compiler can of course call them in any order in the binary.

> Even more simply can we rely on the fact that system calls must be in order?

That is not specified by the C++ standard. System calls do not exist in the standard. Any interaction with the environment specified by the standard happens through C++ standard library functions. There are certain library functions that have observable behavior (i.e. IO library calls) that must produce the observable behavior in the order in which they are sequenced (or happen-before) in the program. These will typically translate to syscalls which then must be in the corresponding order. How the compiler archives this is completely up to the compiler. Typically system calls are ultimately implemented in inline assembly and the inline assembly statements (which are non-standard) will have some options to specify ordering constraints.

> Is there a way to get GCC treat a pure C++ function as a system call or enforce function ordering?

You enforce ordering depending on what exactly you want with the help of `volatile`, `std::atomic`, `std::mutex`, C++ library calls and compiler extensions like inline assembly. You are not specific enough on what ordering guarantees you exactly want, so I can't be more specific.

> In general the answer of what the compiler understands/sees and thus is allowed to optimize away is pretty ambiguous.

No, it is very clearly specified (with some minor ambiguities e.g. for `volatile` observable behavior): The program will have the specified observable behavior on the abstract machine. Not more and not less is guaranteed without additional implementation-specific guarantees.

What exactly observable behaviors are is specified in the standard (C++ standard library IO and `volatile` access) and the semantics on the abstract machine are also specified by the standard (except where it leaves behavior undefined).

Comment: Why isn't impacting program outcome considered an observable effect? It seems when ever you have input/output or opaque system calls reordering shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: In the try/catch example if you specify no-inlune, will ordering of function calls be forced?

Comment: Another obvious issue is when you are working with pointers, say you pass in an address and that address is incremented by 1 to access another entry in an array, and that array is then modified later on or accessed, the modification might be optimized out. In general this framework seems very sketchy for doing anything interesting.

Comment: @FourierFlux As I wrote C++ standard library IO is considered observable behavior. System calls are not, simply because the notion of a system call doesn't exist in the standard. "_impacting program outcome_" is way to vague for a language specification and I am sure that if you were to try to define it more specifically, you would get something similar to what the standard currently says, given the limitations of its scope. What ordering guarantees are made for things not specified by the standard is up to the C++ implementation (or other standards/specifications where applicable).

Comment: @FourierFlux As I wrote in my answer, if the compiler can't reason about the contents of the functions (e.g. because they are in different translation units and LTO isn't used), then in practice the compiler cannot reorder them. But that's an implementation detail of the compiler. If it does see the contents, then it can optimize exactly as I wrote in any way that doesn't change specified observable behavior or affects any other ordering guarantee that the compiler specifically makes.

Comment: @FourierFlux Try to give a concrete example of code where you think there is a problem. To me it sounds like you are simply not using `std::atomic` or `volatile` where it is required to get the defined observable behavior on the abstract machine that you want.

Comment: One obvious issue besides IO timing related tasks where variables may get modified by the system(ex you passed an address in to a prior system call) is threading/multiprocessing. Even the concept of a thread breaks when you allow reordering under the C++ standards.

Comment: Ex, you want one thread to run a function independently, the compiler might produce something where the function gets intermixed with another function.

Comment: @FourierFlux Yes, program behavior is undefined in the face of data races.  You _must_ use some form of synchronization (`std::atomic`, `std::mutex`, etc), to get any sequencing guarantees in multithreaded programs (ok, technically the `std::thread` constructor itself has some sequencing guarantees).

Comment: It's not just data-races in terms of sharing information. Even the concept of a thread doesn't exist as you can't enforce a function is a single block of continuous code.

Comment: So I will give a concrete example without threading. Suppose you pass the address of a pointer pointing to an array which is dynamic. That array is then passed to the OS via pointer where it may modify it and or read it. If your own code modified they array also you don't want the code repositioned but the compiler won't enforce correct ordering for accessing the array.

Comment: @FourierFlux Threads and multithreading are completely well-defined even just by the standard and you get programs with well-defined behavior if you use `std::atomic` correctly as specified in the standard. There is no problem with that. Your example is again vague. I am asking for concrete code. If you call into your OS with a system call then you need to use non-standard functionality anyway which will have options to enforce the necessary ordering. If you use shared memory for communication, then you'll have to use a combination of `std::atomic` and `volatile` as appropriate.