# How to interpret these results for mean filter for both GPU and CPU serial versions?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpu

I implemented image `Mean Filter` code for the `CPU serial` version and `NVIDIA` `GPU parallel` version. I got the running times (Please See the [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT5Tv.jpg) of test cases  and [specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfZuz.png) of the devices. **Why `case 2` has the `highest` speedup and `case 3` has the `lowest` speedup?**

**GPU execution config**

```
        int block_size = 32;
        int grid_size = width/block_size; //width of the image in pixels
        dim3 dimBlock(block_size, block_size, 1);
        dim3 dimGrid(grid_size, grid_size, 1);
```

**time measurement for GPU code**

```
        clock_t start_d=clock();
        meanFilter_d <<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>> (image_data_d, result_image_data_d, width, height, half_window);
        cudaThreadSynchronize();
        clock_d end_d=clock();
```

**time measurement for CPU code (single threaded)**

```
        clock_t start_h = clock();
        meanFilter_h(data, result_image_data_h1, width, height, window_size);
        clock_t end_h = clock();
```

**host code**

```
void meanFilter_h(unsigned char* raw_image_matrix,unsigned char* filtered_image_data,int image_width, int image_height, int window_size)
{
    // int size = 3 * image_width * image_height;
    int half_window = (window_size-window_size % 2)/2;
    for(int i = 0; i < image_height; i += 1){
        for(int j = 0; j < image_width; j += 1){
            int k = 3*(i*image_height+j);
            int top, bottom, left, right; 
            if(i-half_window >= 0){top = i-half_window;}else{top = 0;}// top limit
            if(i+half_window <= image_height-1){bottom = i+half_window;}else{bottom = image_height-1;}// bottom limit
            if(j-half_window >= 0){left = j-half_window;}else{left = 0;}// left limit
            if(j+half_window <= image_width-1){right = j+half_window;}else{right = image_width-1;}// right limit
            double first_byte = 0; 
            double second_byte = 0; 
            double third_byte = 0; 
            // move inside the window
            for(int x = top; x <= bottom; x++){
                for(int y = left; y <= right; y++){
                    int pos = 3*(x*image_height + y); // three bytes
                    first_byte += raw_image_matrix[pos];
                    second_byte += raw_image_matrix[pos+1];
                    third_byte += raw_image_matrix[pos+2];
                }
            }
            int effective_window_size = (bottom-top+1)*(right-left+1);
            filtered_image_data[k] = first_byte/effective_window_size;
            filtered_image_data[k+1] = second_byte/effective_window_size;
            filtered_image_data[k+2] =third_byte/effective_window_size;


        }
    }
}
```

**device code**

```
__global__ void meanFilter_d(unsigned char* raw_image_matrix, unsigned char* filtered_image_data, int image_width, int image_height, int half_window)
{
    int j = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int i = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (i < image_height && j < image_width){
        int k = 3*(i*image_height+j);
        int top, bottom, left, right; 
        if(i-half_window >= 0){top = i-half_window;}else{top = 0;}// top limit
        if(i+half_window <= image_height-1){bottom = i+half_window;}else{bottom = image_height-1;}// bottom limit
        if(j-half_window >= 0){left = j-half_window;}else{left = 0;}// left limit
        if(j+half_window <= image_width-1){right = j+half_window;}else{right = image_width-1;}// right limit
        double first_byte = 0; 
        double second_byte = 0; 
        double third_byte = 0; 
        // move inside the window
        for(int x = top; x <= bottom; x++){
            for(int y = left; y <= right; y++){
                int pos = 3*(x*image_height + y); // three bytes
                first_byte += raw_image_matrix[pos];
                second_byte += raw_image_matrix[pos+1];
                third_byte += raw_image_matrix[pos+2];
            }
        }
        int effective_window_size = (bottom-top+1)*(right-left+1);
        filtered_image_data[k] = first_byte/effective_window_size;
        filtered_image_data[k+1] = second_byte/effective_window_size;
        filtered_image_data[k+2] =third_byte/effective_window_size;
    }
}
```

It can be seen that both image sizes with `3×3` kernel is slower than `5*5` kernel. Case 1 has more parallelism than the case 3 due to the larger image size. Therefore, Utilization of device of case 1 is higher than that of case 3. But I have no idea of interpreting further. Please give me some insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to point out is: **what** are you measuring and most important **how**?
From your question is impossible to deduce especially how.

Anyhow I strongly recommend you to take a look to this, it's a very simple and useful [article](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/how-implement-performance-metrics-cuda-cc/) by Mark Harris, that explains some good practices to sample execution times for device side code (i.e. CUDA memory transfers, kernels etc.).

By the way trying to get a *CPU/GPU speedup* is a quite tricky topic, this is due to the really different nature of the two architectures.
Even if your CPU and GPU codes are apparently doing the same thing, there are a lot of 
factors that maybe you want to take into account (for example CPU cores, GPU Streaming Multiprocessors and cores per SM).
[Here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/945987/what-is-maximum-speed-up-that-can-be-obtained-with-gpu-/) Robert Crovella gives a great answer for a similar problem, as he says:

> If you make any claims about "the GPU is faster than the CPU by XX", then IMO you are well-advised to compare only codes that do the same work and efficiently and effectively use the underlying architectures (for both CPU and GPU). For example in the CPU case you should certainly be using a multi-threaded code, so as to take advantage of the multiple CPU cores that most modern CPUs offer. These sorts of claims are likely to be viewed with skepticism anyway, so probably best to avoid them unless it is the crux of your intent.

I suggest you to take a look to [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/824746/how-calculate-speed-up-with-cuda/) discussion too.

After some premises, I don't think you can consider those speedups reliable (in fact those seem to be a bit strange to me).
Trying to interpret what you were trying to say:

> It can be seen that both image sizes with 3×3 kernel is slower

Maybe there you wanted to say that in 3x3 you obtained a smaller speedup w.r.t. those for 5x5 window size. Try to be more accurate.

> Why case 2 has the highest speedup and case 3 has the lowest speedup?

Well it's really hard to deduce something by the poor informations you provided.

Please add: some code to see what you're doing and how you're implementing the problem in both device and host case, describe how and what you're measuring.

---

EDIT :

Well I think you should take measures in a more accurate way.

- First I'd recommend you to use a more accurate alternative to `clock()`. Take a look  to  answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time) and to C++ reference, I suggest you to consider the use of

```
std::chrono::system_clock::now()

std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

- Then I repeat you to read the article (linked above) by Mark Harris.
  Here he says

  > A problem with using host-device synchronization points, such as `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`, is that they stall the GPU pipeline. For this reason, CUDA offers a relatively light-weight alternative to CPU timers via the CUDA event API. The CUDA event API includes calls to create and destroy events, record events, and compute the elapsed time in milliseconds between two recorded events.

This means the actual results on measures you provided, could be a little "distorted" by the use of `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`.
Furthermore it's not necessary to use a synchronization mechanism if you use simple `cudaMemcpy`, since it's a synchronous call.

- Also think about to include H2D/D2H transfers, according to me it's important to take into account this overhead in a CPU/GPU comparison (but this choice is up to you);
- About the measures you gave in the picture, are they a direct result
  or an average of repeated different executions (possibly discarding
  outlayers values)?

I think you should sample new measures following these above suggestions, and make considerations on new measures obtained.

Btw you said

> Case 1 has more parallelism than the case 3 due to the larger image size. Therefore, Utilization of device of case 1 is higher than that of case 3.

I don't agree with that, since you've `int grid_size = width/block_size;`

CASE 1: *grid_size = 640/32 = 20*

CASE 2: *grid_size = 1280/32 = 40*

So you've an higher amount of parallelism in case 2. But since you've only 2 SM, this could be the reason why the time can be higher than you expected.
In other words you've more blocks (40*40) waiting on the two SM to be computed.

Comment: hv a look at the updated question. Will you now be able to give a good conclusion? "in fact those seem to be a bit strange to me", then what are your expected speedup oder for the given 4 cases?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera Well it's not trivial to determine a speedup order. As I told you, it' difficult to give a relation CPU/GPU time. There are lot of parameters to consider, and reduce this problem to a simpler one, can lead to meaningless comparisons. Btw I'd expect something like (using same grid/block settings): 
- small difference in gpu/cpu times when the input has a sufficiently small size (because H2D/D2H and kernel launch overheads);
- considerable difference with big-sized input (overhead should be hidden by the gpu gain in computing speed).
Now I'm editing my answer based on your quest

Comment: thanks @Maria Chiara Cecconi, As you I calculated the finer granular time elapses.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera you're welcome.
From the same answer by Robert Crovella I mentioned in my answer, there's another interesting remark (that may be usefule for you): _Many codes are either compute bound or memory bound, and as a rough rule-of-thumb, the GPU offers about 5x higher capacity in either case. Therefore speedups significantly in excess of 5x are often viewed suspiciously or taken with a grain of salt._

Comment: I tried to balance the block work for two image sizes. Each block has `32x32` many threads. I'm not limiting the independently execution parts by defining the block size 32. GPU did better than CPU. Could you notice that `5x5` do better than `3x3` for the same image size?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera if you mean 5x5 does better than 3x3 (same image size) in speedup, well I noticed that.
Have you tried other window sizes? 
And Taking a closer look to your code, there are two things I can't understand:
Why do you compute `half_window=(window_size-window_size % 2)/2;` this way? Do you compute that way for Kernel too?  The other thing: Are you sure this index is correct? `int k = 3*(i*image_height+j);`
Shouldn't it be `int k = 3*(i*image_width+j);` instead?

Comment: Yeah I tried different window sizes but still the same. computation is correct. I checked it manually for small sized images and I cross checked the results from gpu and cpu. that calculation for `half_window` is just by assuming filter size is a odd number. half  size was used to check exceeding boundaries. since this is a square filter it is easy to check the boundaries starting from mid point of the filter.