# Measure the execution time of a function

Tags: c++, time, c++14, c++17

I want to measure the time of a function execution.

I could use something like this:

```cpp
using namespace std::chrono;
auto start = steady_clock::now();
// process
auto end = duration<double>(steady_clock::now() - start).count();
```

but I it seems pretty non-[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) to me. So I created a small function to do it:

```cpp
template <typename Function, typename... Args>
auto measure_time(Function func, Args&&... args)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);   // handle lvalues and rvalues
    return duration<double>(steady_clock::now() - start).count();
}
```

and I call it as such:

```cpp
measure_time(func, arg1, arg2, arg3);       // for common functions
measure_time([](){func(arg1,arg2, arg3););  // for member or template functions
```

This works fine for me, but it does come with some drawbacks:

1. it is not clear to me how it be *conveniently* changed to also retrieve the return value of `func`  (which, of course, can also be `void`)?
2. this clearly contradicts with the one-thing-per-function rule
3. the readability of the code is significantly undermined:

   ```cpp
   important_function(arg1, arg2);                // reads well
   measure_time(important_function, arg1, arg2);  // measure_time steals the spotlight
   ```

Are there any guidelines to face these issues?

---

### Update:

I forgot to mention that after the execution of the function I need to store the time elapsed to a container.

---

### Update 2:

after @puio 's answer, I ended up with this:

```cpp
using namespace std::chrono;
template <typename Container>
class Timer{
   public:
    Timer(Container& _c) : c(_c) {}
    ~Timer() {
        c.push_back(duration<float>(steady_clock::now() - start).count());
    }
   private:
    time_point<steady_clock> start{steady_clock::now()};
    Container& c;
};
```

Usage:

```
auto mc = MyContainer{};
...
{
    auto t = Timer<MyContainer>(mc);
    // things to measure
}
// mc.back() is the elapsed time
```

DRY and clean :)

Comment: Benchmarking is not trivial better use a library like this: [Google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark). The optimizer can totally stand in your way. Maybe your function gets never called if the return value is not used and so on

Comment: I guess you could have the type of the return in there too, but makes it looks even stranger.

Comment: For small benchmarks you can also use [quick bench](https://quick-bench.com/)

Comment: @Thrasher Noted. But in this case I want to store the execution times in a container and display them to the user at a GUI. I am not worried about anything being optimized out because the measured functions are triggered by the user.

So this is not benchmarking per se.

Comment: you can look at the implementation of [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to get some inspiration. Its probably much more generic than what you need

Comment: @idclev463035818 even if this work, doesn't it still "hide" the `func` inside `std::invoke`?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I was refering to 1. how to retrieve the return value. didnt suggest to use `std::invoke` but its implementation does already most of what you want

Comment: Beware, `vector::push_back()` can throw, which will crash if happens within a destructor (which is `noexcept` by default).

Comment: @rustyx Thanks for the clarification! So I should declare the destructor as nonxcept(false)? Seems a bit fishy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate this class in a function and it will print the time when the object goes out of scope.

```
class Timer {
 private:
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin;
  std::string_view func_name;

 public:
  Timer(std::string_view func)
  {
    func_name = func;
    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  }
  ~Timer()
  {
    const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << func_name << " Time: "
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()
              << " microseconds " << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
void slow_func(){
  Timer timer{__func__};
  // ...
  // Destruct automatically.
}
```

The `chrono` functions taken from here since I keep forgetting it.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27739925

---

> But I need to store the time elapsed in a container

I imagine it is `std::vector`, pass it by non-const reference (as a return value) to the Constructor, store the reference in `private` access, and `push_back` the time to the vector in the destructor.

A public member function to do so, or calling the destructor explicitly with the said `std::vector` just makes it cumbersome. Also, callers may miss using that function.

Comment: you are not really answering the question, this is just another way to measure time

Comment: @idclev463035818 I solved all the issues OP posted: It follows DRY, readability is good, it does the job, function works as usual and no new bugs are introduced.

Comment: Nice RAII solution. But I need to store the time elapsed in a container (edited in the problem statement)

Comment: the question is "Are there any guidelines to face these issues?"

Comment: @idclev463035818 the title (and the use case) is "Measure the execution time of a function".. The quoted question is just generic "help me out".

Comment: @SteliosDaveas added a hint in the answer :)

Comment: @puio thanks, this is what I was looking for. Updated OP ^

Answer (score 1):

If recording the time is not part of the main goal of your program. You can use GCC [`-finstrument-functions`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) option and provide a definition for the functions:

```
struct Record {
   std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start, stop;
};
std::map<void *, Record> container;

void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *this_fn,
                               void *call_site) {
    auto &record = container[this_fn];
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    // do something with start
    record.start = start;
}

void __cyg_profile_func_exit  (void *this_fn,
                               void *call_site) {
    auto stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    // do something with stop
    container[this_fn].stop = stop;
}
```

Comment: Good to know. But it is part of the program indeed.

Answer (score 1):

> *... it is not clear to me how it be conveniently changed to also retrieve the return value of `func`*

Another possible solution is to return a `tuple` of the duration and (optionally) the function's return value, when it's not `void`.

Something like this (C++17):

```
using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

template <typename Function, typename... Args>
auto measure_time(const Function& function, Args&&... args) {
    auto start = Clock::now();

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<Function, Args...>, void>) {
        std::invoke(function, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return std::make_tuple<Clock::duration>(Clock::now() - start);
    }
    else {
        std::tuple<Clock::duration, std::invoke_result_t<Function, Args...>> res{0, std::invoke(function, std::forward<Args>(args)...) };
        std::get<0>(res) = Clock::now() - start;
        return res;
    }
}
```

Use as:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    auto [dur, res] = measure_time(&some_func, some_args);
    std::cout << "some_func: " << res << ", time: " << dur / 1us << "us\n";
}
```

Notes:

- By creating the tuple together with the invoke result, we benefit from RVO (the result will be stored at the call site, never copied/moved).
- `std::invoke` allows invoking pointer-to-member functions.

Comment: Noted. This is a convenient solution but suffers from the rest of the drawbacks (mainly readability).