# How do I convert std::chrono to int

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have been trying to make a wpm counter and, long story short, am running into an issue:
After using the high resolution clock, I need to divide it by 12, but I can't convert `std::chrono` to `int`. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <synchapi.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
int main()
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Time;
    typedef std::chrono::seconds s;

    string text;
    string ctext = "One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve";

    cout << "Type: "<< ctext << " in" << "\n" << "5" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "4" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "3" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "2" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "1" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "GO" << endl;

    auto start = Time::now();
    cin >> text;
    auto stop = Time::now();

    float wpm = stop - start / 12;
    
    if (ctext == text)
    {
        cout << "Correct! WPM: " << wpm;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You had some errors. Your WPM: " << wpm;
    }
}
```

Are there any alternative methods I could also use to using std::chrono for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time

Comment: you are using `std::chrono` (and there is no `std::int`)

Comment: `start` and `stop` are two timepoint, the result of `stop - start` is a `std::chrono::duration`, so, `(stop - start).count()` should give you an integer.

Comment: @Yves your comment should be an answer ;)

Comment: As you are using `std::chrono`, I suggest to use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) instead of `Sleep(1000)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help and yes, my problem is now solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::chrono will elegantly do this problem with a few minor changes...

- Instead of `Sleep(1000);`, prefer `this_thread::sleep_for(1s);`.  You'll need the header `<thread>` for this instead of `<Windows.h>` and `<synchapi.h>`.
- `cin >> text;` will only read one word.  To read the entire line you want `getline(cin, text);`.
- It is easiest to first compute minutes per word stored in a floating point type.  To get the total floating point minutes you can just divide the duration by `1.0min`.  This results in a `long double`.  Then divide that total minutes by 12 to get the minutes per word:

.

```
auto mpw = (stop - start) / 1.0min / 12;
```

- Then just invert `mpw` to get words per minute:

.

```
float wpm = 1/mpw;
```

In summary:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    typedef steady_clock Time;
    typedef seconds s;

    string text;
    string ctext = "One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve";

    cout << "Type: "<< ctext << " in" << "\n" << "5" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    cout << "4" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    cout << "3" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    cout << "2" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    cout << "1" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    cout << "GO" << endl;

    auto start = Time::now();
    getline(cin, text);
    auto stop = Time::now();

    auto mpw = (stop - start) / 1.0min / 12;
    float wpm = 1/mpw;

    if (ctext == text)
    {
        cout << "Correct! WPM: " << wpm << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You had some errors. Your WPM: " << wpm << '\n';
    }
}
```