# Measuring elapsed time, storing the start time as a primitive type

Tags: c++, c++17

1. I need to measured elapsed time in ms
2. I need to store the start time as a primitive type
3. I need to retrieve the start time as a primitive type, when making the comparison to determine how much time has elapsed

Any suggestions?

I have C++17 and do not want to use any external libraries (like boost).

`std::chrono` would be fine if someone could explain to me how to convert the elapsed time to/from a primitive. I'm not very good at C++.

resolution accuracy is not important.. if it is off by tens of ms that's ok, I just need to implement a delay.. e.g. 100ms or 1.5s

Comment: what means "not want to use any libraries" ? Does that exclude the standard library? WIth language only you cannot measure time afaik.  You can start from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27739925/4117728 and store the start time as primitive type, though frankly that requirement is a little odd

Comment: If you cannot use libraries, does that mean you cant use #include <chrono>? The real question is ofcourse what do you want to measure? Instead of adding code to your code to measure your code you can also use a profiler.

Comment: You might find std::chrono useful in this scenario. Checkout [high_resolution_clock](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now/) example for inspiration.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to store the time as a primitive type? That's an unusual constraint.

Comment: ah sorry, standard library is ok - I meant nothing external.. like boost

Comment: I want to store the time as a primitive due to the limitations of the application that I'm using C++ to build an add-on for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this by:

```cpp
double time = 1000 * ((double)clock()) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

See the below code for better understanding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  double start = 1000 * ((double)clock()) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  for(int i=0;i<1e9;i++);

  double end = 1000 * ((double)clock()) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  double time_taken = end - start;
  cout << time_taken << "ms\n";
  
  return 0;
}
```

**Include the header file:**

```
#include <time.h> // include this
```

Comment: wow nice, and simple - I like it

Comment: Don't use #include<bits/stdc++.h> . Otherwise good solution.

Comment: The example test delay code could be optimized away with release compiler switches.

Comment: @Sebastian Yeah, #include<bits/stdc++.h> would increase the compilation time. I just typed that in my default cpp template. I forgot to mention the header file

Comment: @ycomp Thank you!

Comment: The `clock` function returns the implementation’s best approximation to the processor time used by the program since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related only to the program invocation.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are storing the start time, you should use `std::chrono::system_clock`.  Its epoch is stable, and will not change with time.  Other `std::chrono` clocks have an epoch that may change between runs of a program, and thus time points stored by one run and read back in by a subsequent run may not be consistent.

To get the current time in milliseconds:

```
auto now = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
```

I like to use either a using directive or a namespace alias to make such code less verbose:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto now = time_point_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now());
```

To convert `now` into a signed 64 bit integral type:

```
auto now_i = now.time_since_epoch().count();
```

To convert `now_i` back into a `time_point`:

```
time_point<system_clock, milliseconds> prev{milliseconds{now_i}};
```

To compare time_points:

```
if (now > prev)
    ...
```

Everything above is in the header `<chrono>`:

```
#include <chrono>
```

Comment: thank you, this helps a lot