# How people used to measure time before chrono?

Tags: c++, time

Since C++11 we can measure time as in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
 
long fibonacci(unsigned n)
{
    if (n < 2) return n;
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}
 
int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "f(42) = " << fibonacci(42) << '\n';
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";
}
```

How people used to measure time before chrono? Was there a C++ way to do it or people used to reply on OS specific facilities?

Comment: `time.h` and `ctime`? Reading the number of clock cycles?

Comment: On Windows I used to use GetTickCount function, and also QueryPerformanceCounter/QueryPerformanceFrequency for more accurate measurments.

Comment: On embedded systems, we would hook up an oscilliscope to a test point.  We would assert the test point before the measurement and deassert after.   Actually, we still use this technique. :-)  Recently (in terms of decades), we would use LEDs as test points or connect them to the test point.  This gives a visual representation of the timing.

Comment: There's almost always an OS function in C that, in many cases, predates even C++.

Comment: On embedded systems, we would have a 1ms Interrupt Service Routine (ISR).  We would have a "tick" counter. Reading the tick counter before and after would be used for event timing.  For longer times, we would read the Real Time Clock (RTC).

Comment: Occasionally you'd have a custom timing rig with an equally custom API. Sometimes, and it's getting less common as time goes by, the chrono implementation is dodgy and you have to go old school.

Comment: Before <chrono>, computers just couldn't tell the time. There was no clock in the bottom right corner of the screen, and programmers had to get out the stopwatch to do performance measurements.

Comment: I still don't use std::chrono for my timings (at least not in this sense, I do use chrono a lot for time calculations) but I use profilers to get data on how much time is spent in what part of my code so I don't mix production code with tests. And chrono in the end measures wall time so when the code is not scheduled to run time still passes. I want to know how much cpu cycles a bit of code consumed. And more often then not I found a bottleneck in parts where I didn't think it would be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808398/easily-measure-elapsed-time top answers are chrono, others are no-chrono

Comment: @PepjinKramer I agree with the general advice, but OP is just asking for measuring time. Also not always measureing time is about finding performance bottlenecks, sometimes something needs to happen within a certain fixed time x, and nobody cares if it takes 1ms or 1ns as long as it takes less than x wall time

Comment: Since when do we have <chrono>, was it introduced with C++11?

Comment: C++11 introduced chrono, mainly to meet the needs of the also introduced multithreading API.  C++14 added constexpr and literals to chrono.  C++17 added round, ceil and floor to augment time_point_cast and duration_cast.  C++20 added calendar and time zone support, more clocks, formatting and parsing.