# Measure the execution time of a function call in C++

Tags: c++, windows, execution-time, boost-multi-index

How can I measure the execution time of a line of code in `C++`in `Windows`. I am inserting about 1,00,000 records `boost::multi_index_container` as follows:

```
while(...) //read a single record from a csv file until EOF
{
    ...
    while(...) // split the record into components based on delimiter
    {
        ...
    }
    //insert into boost::multi_index_container
}
```

I need to find the time required to insert all the records, but without the execution time of loops. Starting a `timer` or anything just before insert function and calculating the elapsed time just after the function call gives 0 `nanoseconds` as the result. So I cannot calculate the time by summing up the individual times. What is the solution?

Comment: In principle, you could tackle it like this: 1. Measure time of an empty loop (but make sure it is not optimized away). 2. Measure the time of your insert loop. 3. Take the difference. Devil is in the detail though that if you want to measure, you should measure the optimized code, not debug code. And then, there is a chance, the optimizer makes it harder for you. Check the assembler output to make sure you measure what you think you measure. Since you do not want the file read times as well, you might come up with some additional steps and differences to finally get what you need.

Comment: I wonder why you need this measure it?

Comment: @pradyot: I want a solution for Windows system

Comment: @BitTickler: I will give a try..But not so sure that I understood what u meant..

Comment: @K117: to measure performance

Comment: @Jackzz. it obvious. Why do you need to measure performance?

Comment: Suggestion: if you want to just profile (i.e., this is needed for dev and not for release), use valgrind. That measures clock cycles for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, you can get accurate measurements with [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: QPC gives execution time as 0 for each single insert. As I have mentioned I need the total execution time to insert the one lakh records..

Comment: You may need to measure CPU cycles somehow for something that fine-grained.

Comment: As I mentioned above, if what you want to measure is too small, measure the time it takes to do it multiple times (so it takes a measurable amount of time). Then, the magic operation is "division": ``total_time / N`` if N is the number of times the operation has been performed. Since your loop and file access also adds to total_time, you need comparative runs of the same code without your insert operation. Then ``(total_time - total_time_compare) / N``.

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate of  [How to calculate a time difference in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728068/how-to-calculate-a-time-difference-in-c).
There are many ways to do this. One that I like uses chrono.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <chrono>

   using namespace std;
   using namespace std::chrono;



   int main()
  {
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    //your code here
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();

    cout << duration;
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Time calculated is in microseconds.

Comment: I have tried it already...again it wont give the execution time excluding the loops

Comment: It works fine on my computer. Do you mind if I ask, what  are you doing exactly. Did you try the other methods given in the link.